# during JavaScript Initialization "Cannot set property 'x' of undefined "

Tags: javascript

**when I move the mouse. console tell me that : Cannot set property 'x' of undefined... why this happened? and how the object Initialization....**

```
 <html> 
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
           <div id = "div1">
                    <img id="omna" src="http://online1.map.bdimg.com/tile/?qt=tile&x=0&y=0&z=4&styles=pl&udt=20141102" width="256px" height="256px" unselectable="on" style="position:absolute;user-select:yes;-moz-user-select:yes;-webkit-user-select:;"/>
           </div>

           <script type="text/javascript"> 
               var kMapControl = {

                   mousemovepos : {
                       x:0,
                       y:0
                   },

                   onmousemove : function (ev) {
                       ev = ev || event;
                       // here tell me:this.mousemovepos.x is not undefined
                       this.mousemovepos.x = ev.clientX;
                       this.mousemovepos.y = ev.clientY;
                   },
                   init : function(){
                       var div = document.getElementById("div1");
                       div.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onmousemove, false);
                   }

               };
               window.onload = function(){
                   kMapControl.init();
               };

        </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `ev = ev || event;` is only required for browsers that don't support the W3C event model. Such browsers won't have *addEventListener*, so not much point in the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loosing the context of your object, when assigning the event listener like that. Basically the new `this` inside the `onmousemove` is (most of the time)  bound to the element, that triggered the event. There are two possibilities to resolve that:

Use  `bind()`:

```
init : function(){
  var div = document.getElementById("div1");
  div.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onmousemove.bind( this ), false);
}
```

Use an anonymous function and a pointer to the old `this`:

```
init : function(){
  var div = document.getElementById("div1"),
      that = this;
  div.addEventListener("mousemove", function(ev){ that.onmousemove( ev ); }, false);
}
```

Comment: I prefer the latter - it's less expensive than a call to `.bind`, and preserves the semantic that `this` inside the handler refers to the element rather than the object.

Comment: @Alnitak: Really? Can you point to a jsperf? (not doubting you, just that it's the first time I heard about it)

Comment: @Amadan internally, `.bind` works by returning a closure that's bound to the parameter that was passed, and that in turn calls the original function using `Function.prototype.apply`.  It's just simpler to create your own alias over `this`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @Alnitak—the above also creates a number of closures, most obviously involving *that* but also *div*.

Comment: @RobG AFAIK the above won't close over `div` because it's not used by the inner function.  Indeed (and I meant to say) the code here also creates a closure over that alias, but IMHO it's unnecessary to call a function to do that.  IMHO, `.bind` is really only the better solution when you do not control the lexical scope of the called function.  `.bind` also creates a new function object.

Comment: @Alnitak: Calling `bind` should not be an issue, since it's done only once (at least in the version of the code in my answer). But it may be that, if indeed the closure is using unoptimised `Function.prototype.apply`, it is an extra level of indirection per closure invocation than necessary. It is this "if" that I am not convinced of.

Comment: When I assign the event listener I get a new this? where can I check the information to understand the knowledge points？

Comment: @zhangkai See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Comment: @zhangkai put it this way, it's the same reason your code doesn't read `window.onload = kMapControl.init` - if you had, the `this` inside `init` would have been wrong because only `obj.foo()` maintains context whereas `obj.foo` is just a reference to a function with no context.

Comment: @Alnitak—according to ECMA-262, functions have access to all the variables on their scope chain, which is maintained whenever a closure is created. Compilers might optimise away unused variables within closures, but you're assuming behaviour that isn't specified.

Comment: I think I know more about 'this' now. now I change my code to the below, Is it a wise way? " onmousemove : function (ev) { ev = ev || event; kMapControl.mousemovepos.x = ev.clientX; kMapControl.mousemovepos.y = ev.clientY; }" "init : function(){ var div = document.getElementById("div1"); var that = this; div.addEventListener("mousemove", that.onmousemove, false); }“

Comment: @zhangkai The `var that=this;` is not needed in your code. You never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event, `this` is the event's target (`this === ev.target`). And `ev` does not have `mousemovepos`, so `this.mousemovepos` is `undefined`. And `undefined` does not have `x`, thus the error. Use this:

```
onmousemove : function (ev) {
    ev = ev || event;
    // here tell me:this.mousemovepos.x is not undefined
    this.mousemovepos.x = ev.clientX;
    this.mousemovepos.y = ev.clientY;
}.bind(this),
```

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
mousemovepos : {
       x:0,
       y:0
 },
```

to

```
this.mousemovepos : {
       x:0,
       y:0
 },
```

Comment: You're correct. I should just go to sleep. It's obviously past my bedtime.